# What treatment did Allied Jewish POWs get when captured by the Germans?

Tags: world-war-two, jews, prisoners-of-war

According to Wikipedia, there were about 500,000 American Jews serving in the US forces during World War II, and another 500,000 Jews served other Allied nations.

Some of these servicemen would have been captured by the Germans. What treatment would they have received? Would the Germans have treated Jewish POWs differently?

Note - this is similar to, but not the same as, [How did the Nazis justify the differences in the way they treated Jews v. POWs?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/how-did-the-nazis-justify-the-differences-in-the-way-they-treated-jews-v-pows)

Comment: If the Jews were from Soviet Union then they were to be exterminated either by labour or gas as was the policy of the Reich for All Slavic prisoners. Western POWs did fare better than that, Jew or not. In some instances, Western Jews and their  non-Jewish comrades were segregated and allegedly "trouble-making" jewish soldiers were sent to concentration camps but that's how far it went AFAIK.

Comment: Third Reich denied Geneva Con rights to Soviet POWs based on pretext (illegal) that SU hadn't signed GenCon. But Wehrmacht was instructed to show appropriate behavior to Western POWs (Except Commandos). It also depended on who was holding you and where. E.g. POWs held by Luftwaffe in Germany would fare better than POWs held by SS in Ukraine.

Comment: @NSNoob Seems like you have a decent answer there, why not move from comments to answer?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am at work right now so can't spend time on finding credible sources. By the time I get off, if it remains unanswered then I would answer it properly. But if you have time and feel it can be a potential answer, feel free to build on it and answer it yourself.

Comment: How would the Germans know that a captured US soldier was Jewish?

Comment: @jamesqf dog tags of Jewish American soldiers had the word "H" for Hebrew.

Comment: @jamesqf: As NSNoob says, this was on dogtags and this was I think to allow religious last rites and burial. But there was a Protestant B dogtag also specifically issued to Jews fighting the Germans. I do not know how common this type of dogtag was or when first issued.

Comment: Keep in mind that as many as 150,000 Jews served in Hitler's army as well.

Comment: My grandfather was a bomber pilot that was shot down and spent 1 year as a POW in Germany.  I actually asked him something very similar years ago and he said that there was only one Jewish American (that he was aware of) at his camp, and that he was treated the same as the other Americans.  But also he said since he was a Major he was bunked only with other officers and that their treatment was on a whole much better than others.  Also this was just one camp so it hardly means this treatment was the same elsewhere.

Comment: Aside on Soviet POWs: Treating POWs on the Eastern front according to the conventions of war would have defeated the reason for invading Russia, which was to get Russian food and Russian oil.  Each POW fed was one less soldier fed, as the army was intended to live off the land.  Peter Frankopan discusses this in his WWII chapters in _The Silk Road_.  Of course, it made much better press to say that we're going to kill those commie bastards than to say that we need to kill them so we can eat their food...that would have been to admit that the Nazi "economic miracle" was nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 14):

British and American POW's were treated as POW's. Soviet Jewish POW's were usually treated as Jews, if their national origin could be determined. The justification was that Soviet Union did not sign the international convention about POW's. Of course, this was the official point of view, but actual treatment depended on commanders in the field.

Official point of view was reflected in the so-called Commissar's Order issued before the invasion of Soviet Union. This order prescribed to select Commissars, Communists and Jews from POW's
and shoot them on the spot. But not all commanders obeyed this order. Some high standing German commanders refused to pass this order to the troops. As a result,
Jewish POWS were treated variously on Soviet theater.

Soviet citizens, except peasants carried the so-called "internal passport", where everyone was assigned a "nationality", which could Russian, Ukrainian, Jew etc. Military personnel did not carry this passport. So to determine that someone "is a Jew" was possible only from the words of other POW's, or checking for circumcision.

Corrections and references. The Commissar order is cited in this Wikiedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commissar_Order I do not know whether this citation is complete but it does not explicitly mentioned Jews.
In some documents they were disguised under the name "politically undesirable",
like in this original document:
http://avalon.law.yale.edu/imt/1519-ps.asp
which mentions "politically undesirable nationalities and racial groups".
What happened in reality is described in this Wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_mistreatment_of_Soviet_prisoners_of_war

EDIT. There are many books which address the question, for example,
Alexander Dallin, German rule in Russia, 1941-1945: A study of occupation policies.

Comment: any sources for further reading?

Comment: Most of my sources are in Russian, but this Wikipedia article seems quite informative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_mistreatment_of_Soviet_prisoners_of_war

Comment: thanks - now I need to find what portion of the Soviet military was Jewish to see if that 5% is disproportionate

Comment: This is easy to find out, but my guess will be about 2%. Also see the references I added to my answer, including some original documents.

Comment: One way that the Germans were able to differentiate Jewish from non-Jewish POWs was whether they were circumcised. Also, Allied military personnel carried identity disks or dog tags which listed their religion. Jewish aircrew were instructed to get rid of theirs in the event of being shot down.

Comment: This answer does not deserve as many upvotes as it has because it does not address the question whatsoever.  The commissar order was regarding Bolsheviks and had nothing to do with Jews.  The Avalon Yale document referring to "Racial groups" specifies which racial groups and they are Racial Germans, Ukrainians, White Russians, Poles
Lithuanians, Latvians, Esthonians, Rumanians, Finns, Georgians..  Not a single mention of the Jewish race.  That Wikipedia article mentioned claims that hundreds of thousands of Soviet Jewish POWs were gassed but provides no evidence for that statement.

Comment: @Vincent: There is ample evidence that Jewish POW were sorted after the capture and shot. Together with comissars and communists.

Comment: @Alex, I'm asking for actual evidence, not hearsay, and furthermore I specifically take issue with the references in your answer which don't answer the question at all but are completely unrelated so I don't understand why your answer was upvoted 7 times when it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

In general, the treatment of Jewish POWs was at the "low end" of what it was for others of their "nationality."

POWs who were Soviet Jews were treated very badly--because they were Soviets. Things were a bit worse for men who were both Soviets and Jews, but it was basically "Soviet" that determined their treatment.

POWs who were American or British were often segregated from non Jewish compatriots. They were then given unpleasant tasks that others of their nationality were spared, but still not treated as badly as Soviets or other "easterners," Jewish or not. In the back of their minds, the Germans thought of them as e.g. "Americans."

Put another way, the Nazis considered their POWs "Americans" (or "Soviets") first, Jews second.

Comment: It's true that Soviets, in particular those belonging to the Bolshevik party were treated badly because Hitler blamed Marxist ideology for the Kiel uprising that he believed cost Germany a potential victory in WW1.

Answer (score 2):

The Jewish POWs of Western nations were separated from other POWs, moved to a separate camp at Berga and assigned more hard work. In about 2 months in one camp where the Jews were assigned mining works, 20% of them perished. This is compared to 2% of death rate among non-Jewish POWs. Fortunately to the imprisoned Jews, the war soon came to the end, so only about of 1/5 of them died. If the war continued, they all would eventually die.

Formally Germans claimed that they treated Jewish POWs according the Geneva convention but in reality the conditions differed a lot. On the other hand, on the Eastern front about 60% of all POWs died in camps.

Comment: any sources for further reading?

Comment: @HorusKol http://www.mitchellbard.com/articles/pows.html

Comment: hmm - one specific event doesn't indicate a general policy... for example, not all POW camps and responses to escapes were like what you see in The Great Escape.

Comment: That page doesn't cite sources besides a tv documentary.

Comment: @HorusKol 99.9% of German camps were uttrly brutal, with little to no variation; See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS-Totenkopfverb%C3%A4nde

Comment: The vast majority of all POWs, Jewish or otherwise, died of disease and near the end of the war starvation.  That's a known fact.  Do you have any evidence to support your claim that Jewish POWs were treated worse than other POWs?

Comment: @Vincent no, nearly all Western POWs survived the war.

Comment: @Anixx I was referring to the POWs who died, particularly in the German camps but also the Japanese.  In other words, the vast majority of all POWs "who died", died of disease or starvation.